# 3 d matrix calculation using apply

Tags: r, matrix, apply

Functions like f=tanh the derivative can be written as df=f*(delta(i,j)-f).  When g is a vector or column matrix, this can programmed as follows using a loop, transpose, and apply to calculate df.

```
set.seed(5)
g1<-matrix(rnorm(3),ncol=1)
f1<-tanh(g1)
df1a = matrix(NA,nrow=nrow(f1),ncol=nrow(f1))
df1b = matrix(NA,nrow=nrow(f1),ncol=nrow(f1))
for (i in seq(1,nrow(f1))) {
  for (j in seq(1,nrow(f1))) {
    df1a[i,j] = -f1[j]*f1[i]
    df1b[i,j] = -f1[j]*f1[i]
  }
  df1b[i,i] = df1b[i,i]+f1[i]
}

df2a <- -f1 %*% t(f1)
df2b <- diag(as.list(f1))+df2a

df3a <- (-1)*apply(f1,1,'*',f1)
df3b <- diag(as.list(f1))+df3a

does_m1_m2_match = all.equal(df1b, df2b, tolerance = 1e-5)
does_m1_m3_match = all.equal(df1b, df3b, tolerance = 1e-5)
does_m1_m2_match
does_m1_m3_match
```

How to extend this when g is a matrix, and should be treated as a collection of column vectors.  Here is the loop implementation.  How to do the apply implementation?

```
ddf2a = array(NA,c(nrow(f2),nrow(f2),ncol(f2)))
ddf2b = array(NA,c(nrow(f2),nrow(f2),ncol(f2)))
for (k in seq(1,ncol(f2))) {
  for (i in seq(1,nrow(f2))) {
    for (j in seq(1,nrow(f2))) {
      ddf2a[i,j,k] = -f2[j]*f2[i]
      ddf2b[i,j,k] = -f2[j,k]*f2[i,k]
    }
    ddf2b[i,i,k] = ddf2b[i,i,k]+f2[i,k]
  }  
}

for (k in seq(1,ncol(f2))) {
  does_m1_md_match = all.equal(df1b, ddf2b[,,k], tolerance = 1e-5)
  print(paste('k',k,does_m1_md_match))
}
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if your `f2` and `g2` didn't have duplicated columns, no?

Comment: If `f2` is a matrix then doing `-f2[j]*f2[i]` is most likely not what you had in mind.

Comment: Expanding on what I think was @flodels point: The values going into `-f2[j]*f2[i]` will always be pulling from the same three values. Did you want `-f2[j,]*f2[i,]`, the dot-products of those rows? And  follow-up question. Once you have a stable loop based procedure, why would you need to convert to an apply-based procedure?

Comment: There are duplicate columns in f2 in order to allow comparing the solution with f1.  The actual problem has different data.  I left out the k index in the df2a equation, but have now added.  I thought apply based would be faster than a loop base; if not, the loop approach is fine.